# Auto Property Synthesis Warning in Xcode 5 iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, warnings, objc-protocol

I'm getting a warning in Xcode 5 with the iOS 7 SDK that says

```
Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property declared in a protocol
```

I didn't get this warning in Xcode 4 with the iOS 6.1 SDK.  Any ideas?

Here is my code:

List.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface List : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, MKAnnotation>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
    IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *annotations;

@end
```

List.m

```
#import "List.h"
#import "RSFM.h"
#import "AnnotationDetailView.h"
#import "DTCustomColoredAccessory.h"

@interface List ()

@end

@implementation List
{
    NSMutableArray *title;
    NSMutableArray *subtitle;
    NSMutableArray *displayItems;
    NSMutableDictionary *marketDictionary;
    NSMutableArray *farmMarkets;
    NSArray *keys;
    NSMutableArray *objects;
}
```

I'm getting the warning on the line:

```
@implementation List
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should have received some kind of warning because `MKAnnotation` protocol contains a number of properties and auto-synthesis has never been supported for properties defined in a protocol.

Either remove this protocol from the list you claim to support or implement appropriate properties / accessor methods to fulfil the stated responsibilities.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [iOS docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW2) you need to synthesize `coordinate` in the `MKAnnotation` protocol. Unfortunately, the compiler doesn't give you this information, though it seems to know.